# Avoiding SQL injection in PHP

Tags: php, sql-injection

I have read about db injections 'till I'm red in the eye, forum search, miss-named search search.... So an outright question. I'm using jquery/ajax.

```
var characterReg = /^([0-9a-zA-NP-Z]{27,34})$/;
```

For just basic format validation. that is passed to php. Is it safe to use the result in a DB query? I'm not looking for actual bitcoin address validation just basic format.

```
<?php
include('myConnect.php');
$expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
$path   = '/';
if (isset($address)) {
    // Query db if address exsists.
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM viewers WHERE address = '$address'");
    $info = mysql_fetch_array($data);
    if ($info) {
        // Build cookie data from db row array.
        $bitAdrr = $info['address'];
        $id    = $info['id'];
        $earn  = $info['earnings'];
        $track = $info['tracking'];
        setcookie('user', $bitAdrr . ',' . $id . ',' . $earn . ',' . $track, $expire);
    } else {
        echo 'empty';
    }
}
?>
```

myConnect.php

```
<?php
$addr = $_GET['address'];
// Verify address is correct format.
if (strlen($addr) > 26 && strlen($addr) < 35 && !preg_match('/[^A-NP-Za-z0-9]/', $addr)) {
    $server = 'mysql.myHost.com';
    $user   = 'myUserName';
    $pass   = 'myPassWord';
    $db     = 'myDataBase';
    // Connect to Database
    $connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to server. \n" . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db) or die("Could not connect to database. \n" . mysql_error());
    $address = $addr;
} else {
    exit;
}
?>
```

Possible injections? mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars seems to be really slow. I'd rather not.

Comment: Sorry, but if you use mysql_query in your codebase your program is vulnerable to injections by default. Mysql_query is deprecated due to its vulnerability. See the warning at the top of http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Stop trying to get out of doing the right thing which is to **use parametrized queries**.  It's like you're saying "Hey, can I drive this route in my car without putting on my seat belt?" when the answer is just to put on your seat belt.  And why are you worrying about how "slow" text transformation code is when it's going to be dwarfed by the runtime of talking to the database?

Comment: No, and thank you. When I run it on my windo$e machine it lags. Could you inject this? Sorry the Amount of quick responses has got me a little overwhelmed. Thanks.

Comment: @user2180814 SELECT * FROM viewers WHERE address = '`' and 1 = 1;--`' Just as an example.

Comment: I guarantee you that whatever speed problems you are having are not caused by calling `mysql_real_escape_string`.  Use a code profile tool like XDebug to find where the real problem is.

Comment: Yes. I am certainly not trying to goad you. I do know the server intensive class "A" response. I simply needed a simpler response that did not use an intensive search, function,.... Seriously thank you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.phpThis extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

    mysqli_real_escape_string()
    PDO::quote()

Comment: @Patashu there is nothing it that warning regarding "vulnerability by default". **mysql is as safe as any other driver** if used properly

Comment: @Your Common Sense It is not for a simple reason - SQL passed through the mysql library mixes data and code. Even if you have the most clever escaping mechanism ever, there could always be a flaw in it (for example, many escaping mechanisms were thought to be foolproof until sending them unicode in a certain format made them fail to notice what wasn't right now, but would BECOME an injection by the time it reached the database). Prepared statements separate code and data, so you have a guarantee that CANNOT be broken that data won't be executed as code by one. It's the equivalent of `eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer is to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), which allows the database engine to worry about the correct escaping.

The full details are in the PHP manual, but the summary is that you first prepare by providing a *template* of a statement with question mark placeholders for the variables:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM viewers WHERE address = ?")
```

You can then provide the parameters to substitute:

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $address)
```

And then finally execute it:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

The other aspect to watch out for is it looks like you're trying to do your validation on the client side (in JavaScript) rather than on the server side (in PHP). This is not safe because you cannot validate that all requests are coming from the code running on your page; since the code runs in my browser I can simply choose not to run it and send a request directly to your server with whatever address value I like. Always implement data validation on the server side.

Comment: "looks like you're trying to do your validation on the client side " for the  ajax  post. Not the php.

Comment: The server knows nothing of what I expect from this string. Pardon me you are good but do you see a problem that can be hacked in the code?

Comment: If what you're asking is "please do a security review on this code" then that's far too localized a question for StackOverflow; questions here are expected to be generally applicable to a wide audience, and the general advice I would give is "apply the best practices suggested in the PHP manual by using prepared statements". In the two minutes I spent staring at your code I didn't see a problem, but I don't see why you would insist on such a risky strategy when a more robust solution is available that requires less code to be written by you.

Comment: It looks like it eliminates all of the most obvious SQL injection attacks, yes. However, even if those code is perfect as currently written, future maintainers of this code could easily mess it up; using the safety mechanisms built into the framework simplify _your_ code and make it easier to more safely maintain. Since this is a Q&A site rather than a discussion forum I won't push this issue any further.